# is it possible to make a c-like binary data(structure) in PHP

Tags: php

This is C code.

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct _DATA_PKT_D1
{
    char    length[2];
    char    command[2];
    char    src[64];
    char    lordId;
    char    user_id[20];
    int     level;
    char    isFine;
    char    company_code;
}DATA_PKT_D1;
#pragma pack(pop)

DATA_PKT_D1 *pkt = malloc(sizeof(DATA_PKT_D1);

//send pkt through TCP socket.
```

Data packet is 95byte. 
I know php has also tcp socket function. 
But, is it possible to make the packet exactly same in php? (95 byte I mean)
and send the data through tcp?

I doubt that php has binary level struct functionality...

Any hints plz~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's totall possible to construct binary data with PHP, although a bit, no, a lot, less elegant than with C. You need the pack/unpack functions, that let you write binary buffers from php variables. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

I've implemented UDP servers and clients for binary protocols (even encrypted) in the past, it's ugly but it works. the only thing you should be careful with is endianness.

Comment: I'd say, "endianness" is not "the only" thing to worry about, but definitely one of the most important ones.

Comment: it's the main gotcha I've experienced with this sort of binary data wrangling.